# frequently occuring character in a string in alphabetical order in python without using control flow

Tags: python, python-2.7

The question is to find the most frequently occuring characters in a string. The most frequently occuring characters must be the output in descending order. in case of a tie,i.e, the same occurances, the same frequency characters must be outputted in alphabetical order.

for example:

```
s="aaccbba"
```

the output should be

```
(('a',3),('b',2),('c',2))
```

and not

```
(('a',3),('c',2),('b',2))
```

note: you shouldn't be using control flow statements

the python version I am using is 2.7.5

I even tried using counters, but it's of no help.

Comment: *note: you shouldn't be using control flow statements* is an arbitrary homework restriction; internally, `Counter()` still uses flow control statements, they are just hidden from you by a library.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter("aaccbba").most_common()
[('a', 3), ('c', 2), ('b', 2)]
```

The output can be sorted:

```
>>> sorted(Counter("aaccbba").most_common(), key=lambda v: (-v[1], v[0]))
[('a', 3), ('b', 2), ('c', 2)]
```

but really, there is no real difference between listing `b` first or `c` first; they are otherwise equal.

Sorting the output does double work; `Counter()` already sorted it's items for you, the above just sorts the lot again with slightly different criteria.